# DataFrame inplace modification with return value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, in-place

I am reading Wes McKinney's 'python for data analysis' and saw the following code

```
# Always returns a reference to a DataFrame
_ = data.rename(index={'Ohio':'Indiana'}, inplace=True)
```

Is there a reason to set the inplace change to `_`?

Comment: It is interesting, because `inplace` return `None`.

Comment: I suspect this came about from a refactor from `data = data.rename(index={'Ohio':'Indiana'})`.

Comment: I found it in book in page 198. `Should you wish to modify a data set in place, pass inplace=True:
# Always returns a reference to a DataFrame
In [151]: _ = data.rename(index={'OHIO': 'INDIANA'}, inplace=True)
In [152]: data
Out[152]:
one two three four
INDIANA 0 1 2 3
COLORADO 4 5 6 7
NEW YORK 8 9 10 11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is usually meant to label a variable we don't care about/don't want to use.

This usually makes more sense when you pull out a tuple and don't care about all the values e.g.

```
a, _ = (1, 2)  # pulls out a == 1
```

In this case, with a single value, there is no reason to do it. You can safely clean this code to:

```
data.rename(index={'Ohio':'Indiana'}, inplace=True)
```

---

I suspect this is a refactor from:

```
data = data.rename(index={'Ohio':'Indiana'})
```

which would make the comment *"Always returns a reference to a DataFrame"* make sense (when you use inplace it returns None rather than a DataFrame!).

Comment: The reason I suspect it was a refactor is that inplace is a somewhat new keyword, relative to the book, though it has since gone out of fashion.

Answer (score 1):

We use `_` to represent a value that we don't care about.  It's convention.  The `inplace` argument will alter the object that `data` currently points to along with the `rename` method returning another reference to it.  This statement is a taking the return value from `rename` and assigning it to `_` suggesting we are going to throw it away.  It won't matter because we already have a variable, namely `data` that will be have the results because of `inplace=True`.

Per jezrael's comment.  `rename` with `inplace=True` returns `None` making it completely irrelevant to assign to `_`.

So the answer to your question is, No.